# Alternatives to using what() for exception details in boost

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I am using the following C++ code from the boost library :

```
try{

child c(commandString, (std_out & std_err) > pipe_stream);

} catch(process_error &pe){
    cout<<pe.what()<<" second line"<<endl;

}
```

The commandString is a command like `ls` or any other command. But if a command that does not exist is typed as per the documentation it throws the `process_error` exception. 
I am catching the exception here but not sure if there is a better way to print out the details of the exception or error than `pe.what()` above?

Comment: Well you can obviously print the `commandString`, but ... how can anyone say what would be "better" if you haven't said either what you're trying to achieve or what you already get?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [boost reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/process/process_error.html) about `boost::process::process_error`, you can read this:

> ```
> struct process_error : public system_error {
> };
> ```
>
> **It merely inherits std::system_error** but can then be distinguished in the catch-block from other system errors.

<sup>*emphasis mine*</sup>

If you look then at the [`std::system_error` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error), like all other standard exceptions, `what()` is the way to provide detailed information about the raised error so I would say yes, this is the proper way to print out the exception details.

But since `boost::process::process_error` does not override the `what()` function, it would return the same as a `std::system_error` would.

Comment: I'm confused by your last paragraph. What is the contradiction? "But since..."?

Comment: I think their point was that if OP doesn't like `system_error.what()`, `process_error.what()` isn't going to be any better. i.e., ".what() is correct, but you're probably not going to like it."

Comment: Well in that respect process_error::code() is technically an alternative. Or of course you can use the non throwing interfaces as I've since then compared in my answer

Answer (score 0):

An alternative interface is using `std::error_code`.

There are pros and cons:

- PRO: it enables you to get more detail about *where* an error condition arose. (This is a hypothetical difference because it's not specified whether `what()` may include info beyond an error condition)
- CON: it might not get as much detail as in the exception message
- CON: since some errors are *exceptional*, it's harder to express the possible error conditions in the interface: the error conditions get in the way in a way that *exceptions* do not

  > in your code you might have created this problem by handling exceptions: now how do decide what value(s) to return
- NEUTRAL: you may still have to handle exceptions because exceptions can arise from any related code (e.g. during setup, doing allocations).
- NEUTRAL: the `code()` member of `boost::process::process_error` is likely to be 100% identical to the `error_code` that you get

### Demo

Contrast the implementations and output below:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cefffae01c172ae6)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bp = boost::process;

int using_exceptions(std::string const& commandString) {
    try {
        bp::pstream pipe_stream;
        bp::child   c(commandString, (bp::std_out & bp::std_err) > pipe_stream);
        c.wait();
        return c.exit_code();
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1; // WHAT TO RETURN
    }
}

int using_error_code(std::string const& commandString) {
    try {
        bp::pstream pipe_stream;
        std::error_code ec;

        bp::child c(commandString, (bp::std_out & bp::std_err) > pipe_stream,
                    ec);

        if (ec) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot spawn child process: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            return -1; // WHAT TO RETURN?
        } else {
            c.wait(ec);
            std::cerr << "Error: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            return c.exit_code();
        }

    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1; // WHAT TO RETURN
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto cmd = "/usr/bin/bogus";
    std::cout << "Using error_code: " << using_error_code(cmd) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Using exceptions: " << using_exceptions(cmd) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Using error_code: Cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory
-1
Using exceptions: Exception: execve failed: No such file or directory
-1
```